# WCF Maximum Read Depth Exception

Tags: wcf, web-services

I get the following exception when trying to pass a DTO over WCF services.

```
System.Xml.XmlException: The maximum read depth (32) has been exceeded because XML data being read has more levels of nesting than is allowed by the quota. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxDepth property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 5230.
   at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException
```

The app.config binding looks like this

```
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IProjectWcfService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
      openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="10240000" messageEncoding="Text"
      textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">

        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="">
          <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
        </transport>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
          algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Web.config service behaviour:

```
    <behavior name="BehaviorConfiguration" >
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles" roleProviderName="SqlRoleProvider" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />

        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider" membershipProviderName="SqlMembershipProvider"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
```

And the DTO looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public class MyDto
{
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am pulling my hair out with it.

Comment: Have you changed the configuration on both client and server? I have the impression that I had to match this change on both of them before.

Comment: Pretty unusual to have nesting that deep.  You might have a circular reference.  I'm thinking we need to see more of that DTO; changing the maximum nesting might only be a band-aid solution.

Comment: I solved my issue as I explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537794/error-while-deserializing-the-object-in-wcf

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's a setting called `maxDepth` on the `<readerQuotas>` which you should be able to set to a higher value than 32 (the default). You obviously have set this on the client already (to maxDepth=200), but you also need to do this on the server side - otherwise, the smaller of the two values (between client and server) will be defining the real number used.

Make sure your server side also includes these lines in its wsHttpBinding configuration:

```
<readerQuotas maxDepth="200" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
```

Comment: readerQuotas is a node of binding. so the web.config should be like this:
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
   <binding ...>
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="1000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
   </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

Answer (score 5):

You have to change the binding configuration on both the client and the server to match ...